# Delay when updating document (MongoDB/Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my application, I am attempting to update a object nested in an array as a below. When testing in postman, there is a delay causing me to have to make two requests in order to see the updated value.

```
if (taskStatus) {
    const taskStatusNew = await Board.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        "columns.tasks._id": req.params.id,
      },
      {
        $set: {
          "columns.$[].tasks.$[t]": req.body,
        },
      },
      {
        arrayFilters: [
          {
            "t._id": req.params.id,
          },
        ],
      }
    );
    res.status(200).json(taskStatusNew);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `findOneAndUpdate()` returns the document as it was before the update was applied. So you have to set the `new` option to `true` if you are using mongoose.

```js
const taskStatusNew = await Board.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        "columns.tasks._id": req.params.id,
      },
      {
        $set: {
          "columns.$[].tasks.$[t]": req.body,
        },
      },
      {
        arrayFilters: [
          {
            "t._id": req.params.id,
          },
        ],
        new: true
      }
    );
```

Documentation article for reference: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html

Answer (score 1):

If your question is like to return the updated value then use this,- **{returnDocument: 'after'}**, you just need to add this in other parameter, then it will give you updated value.